# Lucene Update Document Index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, lucene.net

I followed this article http://leoncullens.nl/post/2012/11/18/Full-Text-Search-on-Azure-with-LuceneNET.aspx to setup Lucene Indexing.

It runs smoothly for the most part how can I edit it so that if there is an existing document tied to the id to delete it then re-insert it?

Editing the following method:

```
public void CreateIndex() {


IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(_directory, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED); // Create    the IndexWriter

    foreach (Book book in _bookService.List()) // Use whatever data source you like
    {
        // NEED TO INSERT A CHECK HERE TO SEE IF A DOC EXISTS
        Document document = CreateBookDocument(book); // Create a 'Document' for each row of your data

        indexWriter.AddDocument(document);
    }

    try
    {
        indexWriter.Optimize(); // Call optimize once to improve performance
        indexWriter.Dispose(); // Commit and dispose the object

        Thread.Sleep(60 * 10 * 1000); // Sleep 10 minutes when the index is created successfully, otherwise immediately restart the process
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        indexWriter.Rollback();
        indexWriter.Dispose();
    }
}

private Document CreateBookDocument(Book book)
{
    Document document = new Document();
    document.Add(new Field("Id", book.Id.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO, Field.TermVector.NO)); // We want to store the ID so we can retrieve data for the ID, but we don't want to index it because it is useless searching through the IDs
    document.Add(new Field("Title", book.Title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
    document.Add(new Field("Publisher", book.Publisher, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
    document.Add(new Field("Isbn10", book.Isbn10, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));

    return document;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, there is no such thing as actually updating a Document instance inside Lucene. It's always done as a delete/insert.

Comment: Gotcha how can I check if a document exists then delete it?

Answer (score 1):

we use the Lucene.Net 2.0.0.4, and for 3.0 I think they are the same.

first You need to add the ID as **Field.Index.TOKENIZED**, then you can modify(delete first then insert)the Index.

```
document.Add(new Field("Id", book.Id.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
```

then open the index instead of create the new

```
IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(_directory, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30), false, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
```

there is the delete sample code:

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(_directory);
reader.DeleteDocuments(new Term("Id", book_id_delete));
reader.Close();
```